# How to query on related models with rails and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a `User` model with a related `EnrollmentInformation` model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :enrollment_information
end

class EnrollmentInformation
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  field :type_one, :type => Boolean  
end
```

I'd like to find all users where the `EnrollmentInformation`'s `type_one` field's value is true.

I've tried several variations on this without success. Does anyone know how I can make this query?

```
User.includes(:enrollment_information).where(:"enrollment_information.type_one" => true)
```

EDIT:

Updated query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I would consider embedding the EnrollmentInformation document inside the User, rather than setting up a relationship. Especially since it's a has_one relationship anyway. That way you can do something like:

```
User.where(:"enrollment_information.type_one" => true)
```

Here's the documentation for embedding one document: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_one

As a side note, when you include, it means you are also fetching the related document. If you have Identity Map enabled, it will also be cached in there. The where clause will only operate on attributes of the User objects, and hence, if you use embedded, you will be able to access the embedded attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried "enrollment_information.type_one" as well. There's already quite a few Users, so I'll discuss embedding enrollment_information into user with the other devs and see what they think. I'm not super familiar with Mongo: is embedding an existing document a trivial change (it seems that it would not be)?

Comment: Without knowing the complexity/size of your db, you could setup a rake task to iterate through each enrollment information document, and set the embedded version on the user.

Comment: but if you want to list down all enrollmentinformation then you have to iterate through all user document when you are using embedded document while thats not the case with relationship...

Comment: Thanks. This was the right answer, but we're going to treat this more like AR, as we'd like to move to postgres down the road.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you are ok with getting an array back -

```
User.find(EnrollmentInformation.where(:type_one => true).collect{|enrollmentinformation| 
  enrollmentinformation.user_id})
```